# How can I make my bot find the last message that matches a criteria, e.x ("joe") and send who sent it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using node.js for my bot, and I, like the question stated, need to find the last message in the channel that matches the criteria specified in the code. For example, the command would say, ?joe, and it would find the last message that has "joe" in it, and return the member that sent it. In the server I am going to use it in, the message is very frequent, so I don't think it will hit any message reading limitations.

I did the code in main.js and the commands in separate js files, like this,

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '?'

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command)
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('AbidBot is online!!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
});


client.login();
```

The ping command looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "this is a ping command!",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('pong!')   
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT #1**
Thanks, but it does not seem to be working for me @Lioness100. Can you take a look?

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'joe',
    description: "find joe",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.messages.fetch().then((messages) => {
            // find the message that has 'joe' in it
            const author = messages.find({ content } => content.includes(' joe ')).author.tag;
            message.channel.send(author);
        }
        }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`MessageManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) and [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find)

```js
// fetch the last 100 messages in the channel
message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then((messages) => {
 // find the message that has 'joe' in it
 const msg = messages.find(({ content }) => content.includes(' joe '));
 return msg
  ? message.channel.send(msg)
  : message.channel.send('None of the last 100 messages include the word `joe`!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it didn't work, can you look at my edit in the post and see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, I think I know what's going wrong. Make sure you have an extra set of curly brackets around `{ content }` (change `messages.find({ content } => ...` to `messages.find(({ content }) => ...`)

Comment: ```(node:9112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined
    at C:\Users\...\commands\joe.js:7:85
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:9112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). ```

This is what it is giving me now, although it does compile

Comment: It's giving you that error because it didn't find any messages containing the word `'joe'`. Check my edited answer

Comment: it gave me a "does not contain joe" error message in the discord channel once, but then after that it gave this in cmd:
```(node:6356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [MESSAGE_NONCE_TYPE]: Message nonce must fit in an unsigned 64-bit integer.```
also this ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().``` and ```DeprecationWarning```